# What is python equivalent to TCL "source FILE"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcl

I use TCL daily for work. 
When we write code we write it in a file then
source FILE
in the TCL interpreter to debug syntax and fix the algorithm errors.

Our CAD tool uses tcl so we are frequently using the DB API to access DB objects.

I am learning python, unrelated to my work.

But I want to write the python code into a file and essentially 
"source FILE"
into the python interpreter like we do with TCL.

I have been searching allot and see all kinds on way to get python to execute code in a file, most of the answers are related to executing code from a unknown source, that does not apply here.

import FILE
works, but then I need to examine variables and data objects using

FILE.myvar for example.

Its too much typing, I want to just say
myvar and get the variable value returned for example.

How would I do this in the python interactive interpreter?

Comment: Use IDLE (which comes with Python) or some other tool designed for this job.

Comment: if you have myfile.py, consider `import myfile`. For subsequent sources, use `reload(myfile)`

Comment: If you're doing this to catch *syntax* errors, you need to get an IDE. Syntax errors should be highlighted by your IDE before you ever run your code.

Comment: quick and dirty would be `from FILE import *` if you declare the exported stuff in `__all__`. But the IPython suggestion is also good, as it does similar convenience things in interactive sessions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want features like this, which can make sense for interactive exploration but should almost never be used in a Python program, I recommend [IPython](https://ipython.org/). It's an alternate interactive Python interpreter with a much richer feature set. In IPython, the particular functionality you're looking for is

```
%run FILE.py
```

to run the file in a fresh namespace and then propagate that namespace's contents to your interactive namespace when it's done (so things you defined interactively aren't visible to the script's contents, but you can still inspect the results conveniently), or

```
%run -i FILE.py
```

to run the file in your interactive namespace directly.

That said, IPython is a bit overkill for just this functionality. To "source" a file in a running regular interactive interpreter, you could do

```
with open('FILE.py') as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

or to run a Python file in a new interpreter and drop into interactive mode when it's done, you could do

```
python -i FILE.py
```

at the shell, not in a Python or IPython session.